# Google Sheet Script | Can I access a cell edit history via a script formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with google sheets and I'm trying to figure out a way of how to get the time when a cell is filled in? I would like that access this information via the google sheet script. Is that even possible?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture date & time when cell is edited (google spreadsheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798792/capture-date-time-when-cell-is-edited-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: I'll look into it thank you

Comment: The onEdit() function is often misunderstood.  It only fires on 'user' edits not on changes due to other script or formula actions. [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, I assume the following:

- You want to detect when a particular cell is modified.
- When the modification is detected, you want to print a timestamp in another cell.

If my assumptions are correct, you can use the following example to achieve your requests:

#### CODE

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4") {
    var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('it-IT');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 4).setValue(
      timestamp);
  }
}
```

#### BEHAVIOUR

The code will run when an edit is made on the spreadsheet by a user. It will check if the modified cell is the desired one (`C4` in this example), and if it is a timestamp will be dropped in the time-keeping cell (`D4` in this case).

#### OBSERVATIONS

- This code works for every sheet of the spreadsheet. To make it exclusive to a sheet, you should use *getSheet method*s [as [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)].
- Due to `onEdit` trigger limitations, this code won't run if the modification is made by a script (in opposition to a user edit).
- The timestamp will be printed in the [italian timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Italy) because your name looks Italian to me. Please, forgive me if I mistook your timezone.

#### ALLUSIONS

- [`onEdit(event object)` simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [`toLocaleTimeString(locale)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Please, don't hesitate to write me back any additional doubts or request me further clarifications.

Comment: Thank Jacques for your input. Yes, I am Italian, great catch. I understand the onEdit concept but I'm trying to achieve this functionality without a trigger. All this is meant for a big excel sheet used by multiple people and I would like to run such script after a whole day of work.

Comment: Hi there @FedericoMinelli! I can modify the code to run automatically once a day, but that will be using triggers. Would that be ok for you?

Comment: Jacques that would be amazing if you could do that for me. I think i can implement triggers in my project now.

Comment: Any updates on this @Jacques-GuzelHeron?? Need the same for me too :)